# ASP.NET - How to set optional field in ViewModel class?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Working on ASP.NET project, I am now facing a problem.

- Frontend Data

```
fruits = [
    {
        type: "First",
        size: 50,
        weight: 120,
        optionalParam1: "String",
        optionalParam2: 152
    },
    {
        type: "Second",
        size: 12,
        weight: 160,
        optionalParam3: "Another String",
        optionalParam4: 169
    },
    {
        type: "Third",
        size: 15,
        weight: 190,
        optionalParam1: "String for Third",
        optionalParam5: [1, 2]
    }
]

saleInfo = {
    param1: 12,
    param2: "string",
    param3: 150
}
```

- ViewModel Class

```
public class FruitViewModel {
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic>[] fruits;
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> saleInfo;
    public int total;
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> prevInfo;
}
```

Just want to store this information to the sql server and restore them from the sql db. But I am not sure if it's correct to use Dictionary for this.

Would you guide me how to receive this information and save to the sql db?
Also how to restore this information from the sql db and send to the frontend?

PS. Here the prevInfo parameter is the same as the saleInfo parameter, but as the name means, it's optional. It's null for request, only available for the response.

Comment: Does Frontend data is standard json objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list works fine.

For the first one create a class which mirrors what your front-end expects, something like:

```
public class FruitModel {
     public string type { get; set; },
     public int size { get;set; },
     //the rest of properties you want
}
```

then your ViewModel starts to look like this:

```
public class FruitViewModel {
    public List<FruitModel> fruits;

    //change the rest to match
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> saleInfo;
    public int total;
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> prevInfo;
}
```

the List will be serialised to Array on the front-end. You will need to do some manipulation as well since your data will be encapsulated into a holder object.

if you get the data in a variable called apiData then you will access the rest with apiData.fruits and the first item is apiData.fruits[0] for example.

if you want to make your life easy on the front-end, all you have to do is assign the response data straight to your variables, something like:

```
fruits = apiData.fruits;
```

nothing else needs to change then.

Answer (score 0):

In VB, when using EF, you can make certain types of property optional by adding ? to the end of the field definition in your Model (i.e. make it nullable).  Strings don't need this.
e.g.

```
        Public Property optionalparam1 As String
        Public Property optionalparam2 As Integer?
        Public Property optionalparam3 As String
        Public Property optionalparam4 As Integer?
```

Re. optional parameter 5, not sure about arrays and object elements, I am looking into that myself now.  Good luck ;)

UPDATE:  arrays are like Strings, they are references and so always nullable, so special treatment required.